# How to upload videos to Google Cloud Storage from a GCE VM instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, lamp

I created a LAMP Stack site, and I am hosting it on a Google Cloud Compute Engine VM instance. More specifically, it is a video sharing site, and the videos are currently uploaded and saved to the instance itself.

I was wondering, how can I upload and retrieve videos from Google Cloud Storage instead? Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Howdy ... welcome to Stackoverflow.  The area you want to study is Firebase Cloud Storage ... https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage ... this is the mobile/web interface and APIs for a lot of function.  Firebase Cloud Storage is mapped to Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: @Kolban thank you so much, quick question, my vm instance is able to upload and store videos and then play back on my site. With the help of phpmyadmin's database im able to retrieve the videos and play them using ffmpeg. Why shouldnt I just add more disk space and use my vm instance only to host videos for my video on demand site?

Comment: You can store your videos on the VM. You will pay a higher cost to do this plus you have to manage backups. The correct design stores the video files on Cloud Storage. The users play (download) the videos directly from Cloud Storage which saves you money, improves performance and offers improved storage reliability. I would also look into a CDN to improve the user experience.

Comment: @JohnHanley ohh ok that makes alot of sense. The way I have it set up right now is ffmpeg is my player and needs a directory of where the video is to play it. When I upload to google cloud storage there isnt a directory ffmpeg can refer to. I have been trying to search for ways to do this but im stuck here

Comment: OK, that is a different application. I thought you were trying to `deliver` video to users. In your case you are `processing` uploaded videos that are stored on your VM. That needs to be done on the VM (or using an external service that supports Cloud Storage). Then you can upload the processed videos to Cloud Storage. There are tools such as `gsutil` and Google SDKs that can copy the video files once processing is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Well the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets) is pretty straightforward on this:

Once you've SSH'ed into the Compute Engine instance, you can use the [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#linux) CLI to upload or download certain files into / from Cloud Storage with [`gsutil cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp). For example, the following CLI command would copy a local file to the desired Cloud Storage bucket:

```
gsutil cp /path/to/my-file.mp4 gs://my-bucket
```

Although, in your use-case it would make more sense to do it programmatically by using the [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) which are available in multiple programming languages. Let's say you want to use PHP for it:

- You would first have to install the Client Library with:

  `composer require google/cloud-storage`
- Set up authentication by first creating a [Cloud IAM Service
  Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication), [giving it a role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource) to access
  the Cloud Storage bucket(s) (in this case the role
  [`roles/storage.objectCreator`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#standard-roles) would suffice if you simply want
  to upload objects), downloading the `JSON` key file into the Compute
  Engine instance, and setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with:

  `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"`
- And then finally, you can upload a file with [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/src/copy_object.php) sample code in PHP. There are multiple examples offered by Google Cloud when interacting
  with Cloud Storage that you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects).

Alternatively, you can mount a Cloud Storage bucket as a filesystem on the Compute Engine instance, as described in the [following](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets#mount_bucket) page.

Comment: would this be ideal for a site that has videos? I am using ffmpeg as my video player and I need the path to my videos. I was looking into google cloud storage but I was also wondering why wouldnt I just get  a vm instance with bigger disk space and continue using vm instance only for my site?

Comment: @yiby32 Well that really depends on the amount of storage you need. Theoretically, yes, you can use the VM for file storage if it's a relatively low amount of capacity that you need. Although if the site grows to serve a very large amount of files, Cloud Storage would be ideal, as it's designed for such scenarios and would be cheaper in the long run, but it's up to you to estime the costs. The [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/) may help in this regard. Having a look at the pricing for GCE and GCS is recommended aswell.

Comment: is firebase storage same as cloud storage? seems like that might be the best way to do it

Comment: @yiby32 Yes and no. Firebase Storage is essentially Cloud Storage but for Firebase apps, facilitating communication to the app; thus unless you're going to build a Firebase app, I don't see a reason to use it. In regards to FFMPEG and Cloud Storage, take a look at the [following](https://video.aminyazdanpanah.com/start/open-clouds) article, which explains how to stream videos from Cloud Storage with the `openFromCloud` method.